# How to get consistent results (for same input multiple runs) of image stitching using opencv?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, image-stitching, ransac, opencv-stitching

I am observing different stitching results (on multiple runs for input images) using opencv.

As i know opencv uses RANSAC for getting inliers and calculate homography. So results might vary?

Is there any way to fix it to get same results consistently ?

If not, how people used to benchmark their results while using RANSAC?

Comment: are u using the same set of images on each iteration or different? What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @ahmed_faraz yes, I am using same images for each run. I am observing changes in output on multiple run. Why? I am using opencv for android